# Node add form set entity reference default selection based on content from another type node

Tags: 8, hooks

I wrote module with *hook_form_alter* to modify *node_forum_form*, i.e., node/add/forum form. One forum field is a taxonomy entity reference, *field_topic*. I want to set the *field_topic* selection based on the value from a specific node (NID=77) of type *current_topic*, which also has *field_topic* as an entity ref.

*field_topic* is ref to Topic taxonomy.

After loading node 77, I got the TID of the *current_topic field_topic*, loaded the term, and then got the term name. Name is displayed on the form above the title using `$form['title']['#markup']`.

Problem:  Before returning the form, how can I set the form default selection to be that same *field_topic* value?

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id != 'node_forum_form') {
    return FALSE;
  }
  else {
    $nid = 77;
    $node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid);

    $current_topic_id = $node->get('field_topic')->getString(); //get the TID
    $term = Term::load($current_topic_id);
    $the_topic = $term->getName();

    $form['title']['#markup'] = t('<h3>The Current Topic is:  <i>' . $the_topic . '</i></h3>');

    // REPLACE THE NEXT LINE WITH CODE TO SET THE CURRENT TOPIC
    $form['field_topic']['widget']['#options']['_none'] = 'Click & Select the Current Topic';

    return $form;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose with

> set the form selection

you mean the default value of the taxonomy term reference field?

If yes, in the code above try this:

```
$form['field_topic']['widget']['#default_value'] = $term->tid();
```

Btw. you also want to change your implementation from `MYMODULE_form_alter` to `MYMODULE_form_node_forum_form_alter`, because the former hook will be called for all forms, whereas the latter is just called when the forum node form renders.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. With a small change it worked perfectly!  `$form['field_topic']['widget']['#default_value'] = $current_topic_id;`

Answer (score 0):

The $term->tid() was calculated earlier in the code. That was the solution.

Comment: While this all works perfectly for admin users, authenticated users see only **'- Select a value -'** as the default value. I verified with set_message that the code knows the correct default value of the taxonomy term. What could be causing this?

Comment: Note in case of authenticated user, `<option value="_none">` is the only item in the select list. For admin user, the select list contains all of the taxonomy items with the  correct option value set to `selected="selected"`.